# iOS - Can I trigger a segue based on tap in container view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, segue, uicontainerview

I have a `UITableViewController` called ListViewController set up (well it is actually a Parse.com `PFQueryTableViewController`, but that is by-the-by) and at the top of the UITableView I have a `Container View` which has a `UITableViewController` embedded within it.

The embedded `UITableViewController` has a couple of static cells in it. What I would like to do, is to **trigger a segue** from from the ListViewController to another view (Navigation Push) when the user taps on one of the cells within the **embedded** UITableViewController.

I have seen other questions about passing information from view to view, but this is specifically for how I might go about triggering a segue.

**NOTE: I am developing the app in Swift**

Comment: The segue being connected to the parent view controller? Do you need to use a segue?

Comment: Wain - let me clarify...I am wanting to push another view (let's call it "DetailListViewController") from the ListViewController based on a tap of a cell in the embedded UITableViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set up a delegate relationship between the embedded table view controller and your `ListViewController` so that when the embedded table cells are tapped the delegate callback is fired. The callback handler (part of `ListViewController`) can then trigger the segue.

So the embedded table view controller has a delegate property that can be set, and `ListViewController` implements the delegate protocol.

Comment: How would I set up such a delegate and 'callback' maybe a code example? I have not used container views before (sorry if this is a basic question!)

Comment: The container views are irrelevant, it's a relationship between the 2 controllers. I don't really do swift at the moment and you want a swift example so you'll need to look for a generic swift delegate tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Wain :) Just to clarify also, I will need to create a class for the contain view to link this all up correct?

Comment: You need to create a protocol, but you shouldn't need an extra class, and the views don't change at all. The `ListViewController` adds itself as a delegate of the embedded controller (which I guess is already added in code?)

Comment: I am using storyboards, so no delegates added in code that i know of

Comment: The `ListViewController` has an outlet to the embedded controller? Hopefully the embedded controller is a child rather than hidden in the container view?

Comment: I have added the container view as per this tutorial: http://www.mikebobiney.com/2014/09/28/static-table-view-containers/

Comment: For anyone else trying to solve this problem, I found this link explained easily how to set up the delegate protocols and methods...and its in Swift! :) http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/

Answer (score 1):

I have [**a project on Github called "Test"**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test.git) (link) that shows how to set up static table views inside a container view and connect 2-directional communications between the table view controllers and their parent view controller.

It's written in Objective-C, but the technique is the same in Swift.

You set up a protocol that the table view controller uses to communicate with it's parent view controller.

You connect the container view in the parent to the child table view controller(s) using embed segues.

You add a prepareForSegue method in the parent view controller that sets up the  parent as a delegate of the child (you can't use the property name "delegate" since it's already used; use something like "parentVCDelegate")

Then when the user taps a cell in the table view, it's view controller sends messages to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a segue to the table in the container. Don't worry it will find the parent nav controller automatically.